# Text field can't be set with returned value of a function

Tags: javascript, return-value

I have text field defined like this-

```
<input type="text" name="minutes" id="Duration_Minutes"/>
```

along with two other fields for Timein and Timeout.

Following function returns the value of total time in minutes (differnce of timein and timeout).

```
function timespent(){
                var starttime = $j("#time_start").val(),
                    stoptime = $j("#time_end").val();
                 .
                 .
                 .              
                var totalminutes = (hours * 60) + minutes;
                alert(totalminutes);
                return totalminutes;
                }
```

On the change event of timein, I want to set the value of text field based on the returned value from the above function as follows.

```
$j('#time_start').change(function() {
                var newvalue= timespent(); 
                                alert(newvalue);
                $j('#duration_minutes').val(newvalue); //this does not work
```

The last line of code does not work. why?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: javascript is case-sensitive  - `Duration_Minutes` is not the same as `duration_minutes`

Comment: @Rhumborl More precisely, I think it's the case-sensitivity of HTML IDs that is the issue here.

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava No, that's not what OP is trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to case sensitivity; corrected that. It didn't help though.

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava - Please excuse me I am a newbie to JS. i don't get it, why should we use change event on duration_minutes. I changed my last line of code with yours and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Thank you @ArpitSrivastava and Rhumborl.. I had problem with case -sensitivity; changed D to d but left M as such before. It works perfectly as -$j('#time_start').change(function() {
          $j('#duration_minutes').val( timespent() );
         });